# cdk-global-scrollblock not getting applied in Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I am facing some issue with Angular Material Dialog.
 have few dialog in the application in all the dialog I can see that cdk-global-scrollblock class is getting applied in html tag but in one of the Dialog it is not getting applied.
I am not sure how to fix it as everything looks same as other dialogs.
Can someone suggest what am I missing.

Comment: I too am facing the same problem. It gets added in few cases and not in few.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Running into the same thing

Comment: Any news/help on this?

Comment: For me this is the issue:
"The dialog won't try to block scrolling if the page isn't scrollable." (therefore it won't add the class)
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16864#issuecomment-524523540

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found the solution in the forum of the lib I'm using, see if this solves it for you, add it to the modal component

```
    /deep/ .cdk-global-scrollblock {
        position: static !important;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/2076